# Visual Studio 2012 SP3 changing link href when using ASP.NET in design view

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I'm using VS 2012 SP3 in which i have an ASP.NET web site.
In my "Default.aspx" i have the following link

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" runat="server" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Whenever i use the design view to for my page like inserting a new row in table in changes it to

```
<link href="http://localhost:50309/netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" runat="server" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Which is becoming pretty annoying.

Does anyone have any idea about how to disable this feature ?

I would also like to note that I have Productivity Power Tools 2012 installed Web Essentials 2012 (but i've disabled them both and still not luck
Thanks!

**Update 1:**
**Steps to reproduce**

- Create a new .aspx page
- Paste `<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />` between the head tags.
- Go to split view
- Write some text between the divs
- The href changes to `<link href="http://localhost:50309/netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />` (port may vary :D)

**Update 2:**
**Microsoft Bug Report Connect Link**

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/793557/visual-studio-2012-changing-link-href-when-using-asp-net-in-design-view#details

Comment: Try playing with the settings in:
tools -> options -> text editor -> html
or
tools -> options -> text editor -> xml
.... particularly under the miscellaneous category.

Comment: Sorry i couldn't find anything that help

Comment: Does it continue to do it if you put `href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bo...`?

Comment: @zeroef It apparently works with http in front but now when i edit and save in source view i keep getting "Unable to edit <<link here>>. The style sheet must be part of the current project and the project must be a Web Site or a Web Application", which is even more annyoing

Answer (score 3):

When using the ASP.NET Script Bundles, you can provide the CDN locations where your script library can be found. When you also add the code locally you get the benefit of being able to debug against the non-minified version while the CDN version will be used when the site runs in production.

See the [following documentation on setting up script bundles on ASP.NET Web Forms](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/08/14/adding-bundling-and-minification-to-web-forms.aspx).

basically you need to add a couple of lines to the Global.asax:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}
```

And then create your bundle as follows:

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
    //bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
    //            "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

    bundles.UseCdn = true;   //enable CDN support

    //add link to jquery on the CDN
    var jqueryCdnPath = "http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js";

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery",
                jqueryCdnPath).Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

    // Code removed for clarity.
}
```

And reference it like this:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">        
     <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
     <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery") %>
     <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui") %>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

This should please both the browser *and* the editor.

---

You can also configure the `<scriptmanager>` to automatically fall back to the CDN using the following pieces of code:

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" EnableCdn="true">
    <Scripts>
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery.ui.combined" />
    </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

And this configuration:

```
var mapping = ScriptManager.ScriptResourceMapping;
// Map jquery definition to the Google CDN
mapping.AddDefinition("jquery", new ScriptResourceDefinition
{
    Path = "~/Scripts/jquery-2.0.0.min.js",
    DebugPath = "~/Scripts/jquery-2.0.0.js",
    CdnPath = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js",
    CdnDebugPath = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.js",
    CdnSupportsSecureConnection = true,
    LoadSuccessExpression = "window.jQuery"
});

// Map jquery ui definition to the Google CDN
mapping.AddDefinition("jquery.ui.combined", new ScriptResourceDefinition
{
    Path = "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.2.min.js",
    DebugPath = "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.2.js",
    CdnPath = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js",
    CdnDebugPath = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js",
    CdnSupportsSecureConnection = true,
    LoadSuccessExpression = "window.jQuery && window.jQuery.ui && window.jQuery.ui.version === '1.10.2'"
});
```

Read the following blog by [Scott Hanselman for more details](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CDNsFailButYourScriptsDontHaveToFallbackFromCDNToLocalJQuery.aspx).

Comment: I really appreciate what you did, i know about bundles, but my problem is the editor, i shouldn't do that it's not normal and if there's a feature that does that i don't know which one is it. I'm just using if for some tutorials and it's acting really weird, there are other problems but i don't know how to reproduce them. Up vote anyway and thanks but this is not the answer i'm looking for.

Comment: These bundle and mapping techniques actually make the editor issue go away and provide a better experience in general in ASP.NET, which is nice too :)

Comment: i did that already waiting for an answer, i'm just curious if some else managed to reproduce it among other things, and btw it works if delete the localhost part, it's just annoying to do that after every edit in design view.

Comment: Pasted the link, if i get an answer i'll post the reply

Answer (score 2):

The VS designer is picky about URI formats in a link tag, and it will "fix" any href that it does not approve of.  The result is not always helpful.

In your case, the issue is that your href is missing a scheme name.  VS should stop rewriting your href if you change your link tag like this:

```
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Side Note: After you fix the href, the designer may complain that it can't edit the style sheet.  I don't know why it does that with this particular file, and I have not seen it do this with other CSS.  Just ignore the warning, and the style sheet should be applied correctly.

Comment: Thank you, but as you can see in the comments i've already tried that, and it's even more annoying than what's currently happening