# How do I user a protocol-relative URL in the HEAD of an ASPX masterpage?

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to reference the following CSS in the head of my masterpage template.

```
<link rel="stylesheet nofollow" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

However, when it's rendered it renders as...

http://www.example.com/maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css

...which is giving me a 404.

What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are possibly causing an error by adding nofollow into the link tag see here

[Do I need rel="nofollow" in external scripts and stylesheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21196528/do-i-need-rel-nofollow-in-external-scripts-and-stylesheets)

**Edit:** update based on OP comment

This seems to be a known issue with older versions of visual studio. for starters you can try the following

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

This may produce another popup. if that is the case you can try to either format the document (ctrl+K, ctrl+D) visual studio can sometimes clear this error if you have consistant line endings.

Reference: http://forums.asp.net/t/1176284.aspx?Could+not+edit+because+it+is+not+in+the+web+site+

If this does not work then you can try and bundle the scripts by following the advice for this SO post [Visual Studio 2012 SP3 changing link href when using ASP.NET in design view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17600154/visual-studio-2012-sp3-changing-link-href-when-using-asp-net-in-design-view)

The optimal recommendation though just seems to be to update visual studio if possible. know Visual Studio versions with the error VS2008 pre SP1

Comment: I was having problems with Visual Studio trying to edit the external CSS files. Adding nofollow seemed to prevent it from constantly prompting that it couldn't edit the file. If there's another better way to turn that off I'm very interested.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid hardcoding http because pages using this master template might be http or https. Scriptbundles seem like fantastical overkill for something as simple as trying to reference a plugins css. I see a whole lot of unnecessary compilation in my future.

Comment: probably and unfortunately I do not have any other ideas for this issue.